# Transferring money for someone

Tags: banking, scams

I met someone and we have been chatting via phone for awhile. He asked me to access his bank account and transfer money to someone else because he is in Thailand on business and he can't access his account.  His bank is the ISBank and is not available in Thailand. He didn't transfer money to me and hasn't asked me for money. Is this a scam?

Answer (score 8):

It is a scam.

Potentially, the access data was stolen, and by *you* doing the transaction, the police will come to *your* door, and *jail* you, not him. Or any of a dozen other illegal things.

Think about it, would you give a chat-stranger on the internet full access to your money?